# How to save data using multiple threads in grails-2.4.4 application using thread pool

Tags: multithreading, grails, grails-orm, threadpool, executorservice

I have a multithreaded program running some logic to come up with rows of data that I need to save in my grails (2.4.4) application. I am using a fixedthreadpool with 30 threads. The skeleton of my program is below. My expectation is that each thread calculates all the attributes and saves on a row in the table. However, the end result I am seeing is that there are some random rows that are not saved. Upon repeating this exercise, it is seen that a different set of rows are not saved in the table. So, overall, each time this is attempted a certain set of rows are NOT saved in table at all.     GORMInstance.errors did not reveal any errors. So, I have no clue what is incorrect in this program.

```
    ExecutorService exeSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30)
    for (obj in list){
     exeSvc.execute({-> finRunnable obj} as Callable)
    }
```

Also, here's the runnable program that the above snippet invokes.

```
    def finRunnable = {obj ->
     for (item in LIST-1){
         for (it in LIST-2){
          for (i in LIST-3){
            rowdata = calculateValues(item, it, i);
            GORMInstance instance = new GORMInstance();
            instance.withTransaction{
             instance.attribute1=rowdata[0];
             instance.attribute2=rowdata[1];
             ......so on..
             instance.save(flush:true)/*without flush:true, I am 
              running into HeuristicCompletion exception. So I need it 
              here. */
            }//endTransaction
          }//forloop 3
         }//forloop 2
     }//forloop 1
    }//runnable closure
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/async.html ?

Comment: Thankyou. But I would really like to understand what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: After close observation of the output of the above mentioned program, I found out that more than one thread is working on the same "obj". In my for loop, I was expecting to have one obj per thread with the following line - `exeSvc.execute({-> finRunnable obj} as Callable)`. Turns out, that's not how it is. There's more than one thread working on the same "obj" instance. I have no clue why that is the case.